# show array from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I have this db

```
id | domain    | whois_server         |
---------------------------------------
1  | ac        | whois.nic.ac         |
2  | ae        | whois.nic.ae         |
3  | id        | whois.pandi.or.id    |
```

How to show array form array without id ?

```
array (
    'ac' => 'whois.nic.ac',
    'ae' => 'whois.nic.ae',
    'id' => 'whois.pandi.or.id',
)
```

I have done the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM whois_server ";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $whoisservers =  array_merge($whoisservers, array_map('trim', explode(",", $row[1])));
}
```

but what appears is :

```
array (
    [0] => whois.nic.ac
    [1] => whois.nic.ae
    [2] => whois.pandi.or.id
)
```

Comment: Why you don't use this query `SELECT domain, whois_server FROM whois_server` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM whois_server ";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$dataReturn = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $dataReturn[$row['domain']] = $row['whois_server'];
}
print_r($dataReturn);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you can add the key to the `$whoisseervers` variable for each value:

```
$sql = "SELECT domain, whois_server FROM whois_server";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();

$whoisservers = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $whoisservers[$row['domain']] =  $row['whois_server'];
}

print_r($whoisservers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$whoisservers = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $whoisservers[$row["domain"]] = $row["whois_server"];
}
```

would be simpler (and clearer).

And as mentioned in the comments, in the SQL don't select fields you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the `$whoisservers` array, by pushing the index as `$row['domain']` and the value as `$row['whois_server']`.

```
$whoisservers = [];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM whois_server ";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $whoisservers[$row['domain']] =  $row['whois_server'];
}
print_r($whoisservers);
```

Answer (score 1):

A little different from other answers solution with `fetchAll` and `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR`:

```
$sql = "SELECT domain, whois_server FROM whois_server";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$whoisservers = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
print_r($whoisservers);
```